# How to define a function that only accepts string

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

Hello I'm newbie in python and I wanted to know if I can create a function that only accepts certain types of values, in this case string, else error

```py
 parameter that needs to be string
            |
            v
def isfloat(a):
    if a.count('.') > 1:
        return False
    for c in a:
        if c.isnumeric() or c == '.':
            v = True
        else:
            return False
    return v
```

Comment: If you want to know whether `a` is `str`,you can use `isinstance(a,str)`.

Comment: `if not isinstance(argument, str): raise ValueError('argument has to be a string')`

Comment: Instead of image, Always add your code so that we can test it instead of rewriting it again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Python 3.5+ you can use [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) to annotate your function:

```
def isfloat(a: str):
    # More code here...
```

But type annotation doesn't actually check types!

So, it's better to add robust type check with [assert](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_assert.asp) statement:

```
def isfloat(a: str):
    assert isinstance(a, str), 'Strings only!'
    # More code here...
```

With `assert` your function will raise `AssertationError` if `a` is not a string.

Answer (score 0):

You could enclose your code within an if statement such as the following.

```
def enumerico(a):
    if (isinstance(a, str)):
        <your code>
    else:
        <throw exception or exit function>
```

Comment: Note that `type(a) is str` returns `False` if `a` is an instance of a `str` subclass. `isinstance(a, str)` is better.